# Refused to frame ‘https://my.matterport.com/’ because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “frame-ancestors ‘self’”

Tags: security, iframe, netlify, matterport

I’m trying to add Content Security Policy to my Gatsby x Netlify website through a `_headers` file. Everything works fine, except for a Matterport iFrame that doesn’t want to be displayed. The error message I see in the console is

```
Refused to frame 'https://my.matterport.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

In my headers file, I added the following X-Frame-Options:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://*.matterport.com/
```

And I also have this `frame-src` in my Content Security Policy:

```
frame-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/ https://my.matterport.com https://matterport.com;
```

But the iFrames still look like this:
[Matterport iFrames not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvAr.png)

Can someone help me figure out what I’m doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came accross the same error message and corrected this by removing a double forward slash before the video link, my original iFrame inclusion looked like: https://my.matterport.com/show//?m=XXXXXXX replacing this with https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=XXXXXXX was enough to get the iFrame showing again.